# Object expiration of non current version

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with a lifecycle rule which sets the `NonCurrentVersionExpiration` to 30 days. Is there a way to see the expiration for the non current version? When using the below CLI call, for example, there is no expiration date header.

```
>aws s3api head-object --bucket <<BUCKET>> --key <<KEY>> --version-id=
null
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "ContentType": "text/plain",
    "LastModified": "Wed, 15 Apr 2015 20:22:53 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 306,
    "VersionId": "null",
    "ETag": "\"6a0b8ed211a784670d0114c603b3eb5a\"",
    "Metadata": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer in the [S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html#RESTObjectHEAD-responses):

> Note that for versioning-enabled buckets, this header applies only to
>   current versions; Amazon S3 does not provide a header to infer when a
>   noncurrent version will be eligible for permanent deletion.